# Faker gem with seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, faker

I am looking to refactor my `seeds.rb` file.  As such, I am relying heavily on the `gem faker` to populate data.

First I'm generating users, like this:

```
# --== Generate Sample Users
  user_list = [
    [ "Name", "Lastname", "Password", 't', "email@something.tld", "Password"],
    [ "Mortimer", "Snerd", "Secret", 'f', "mortimer@snerd.net", "Secret"]
    5.times.do
      name = Faker::Name.first_name
      surname = Faker::Name.last_name
      password = Faker::Internet.password(10)
      [ name, surname, 'f', Faker::Internet.email(name + "." + surname), 'f', password, password]
    end
  ]
    user_list.each do |name, surname, admin, email, password, password|
      User.create( name:name, surname:surname, admin:admin,  email:email, password:password, password_confirmation:password )
    end
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error: `unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ']'
    5.times.do`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hint: It's expecting a `]` at the end of the `user_list` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `5.times.do` isn't valid syntax. `5.times` returns an Enumerable object, but `do` isn't a method. I think you mean to use `do` as a block here.

Also, passing a block to `times` doesn't return an array, it just returns the last item returned from the block, so you're not actually modifying your `user_list` array

```
user_list = [
  [ "Name", "Surname", "Password", 't', "email@example.com", "Password"],
  [ "Mortimer", "Snerd", "Secret", 'f', "mortimer@snerd.net", "Secret"]
]

5.times.do
  name = Faker::Name.first_name
  surname = Faker::Name.last_name
  password = Faker::Internet.password(10)

  # Add user to user_list
  user_list << [ name, surname, 'f', Faker::Internet.email(name + "." + surname), 'f', password, password]
end

user_list.each do |name, surname, admin, email, password, password_confirmation|
  User.create(name: name, surname: surname, admin: admin,  email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password_confirmation )
end
```

Finally, you may want to forgo using Faker for emails and use `find_or_create` instead of `create` to prevent creation if a user already exists with a given email. Your `seeds.rb` should really be idempotent (running it more than once should have no side-effects).

Comment: What would you suggest instead of Faker?

Comment: Just pass `i` to the block of `5.times.do` and use something like `email = "seeduser#{i}@example.com"`. Then use `User.find_or_create_by(email: email, ...)` so you're not creating new users each time.

Comment: So why won't the following work?

`5.times.do |i|`
  `name = Faker::Name.first_name`
  `surname = Faker::Name.last_name`
  `password = Faker::Internet.password(10)`
  `user_list << [ name, surname, 'f', Faker::Internet.email(name + "." + surname), 'f', password]`
`end`

Comment: Well, `5.times.do` should be `5.times do`. If you run your `rake seed` more than once you'll start getting a bunch of users you probably don't want. Not a big deal, but might make things messy. May as well ensure that you're only creating seed users once.

Comment: Right you are.  Noob mistake including the '`.'`  You put me on the right path, so I marked the answer as correct.  However I ended up using `(0..x).map { ... }` instead.

I can now populate my database in fewer than 50 lines of code.  Thanks.